# How to read an attribute value from Controller Class custom attribute

Tags: c#, attributes

I am defining a custom attribute on controller to perform security functions. How can i read the value of attribute for example

```
[NavAttribute(Navigation = "Home")]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [SharePointContextFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code will give you the attributes of a class.

```
typeof(HomeController).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NavAttribute), true);
```

For a Method

```
typeof(HomeController).GetMethod("Index").GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SharePointContextFilter), true);
```

Comment: can i make a static function that could read the value of attribute such as if i send the object of controller to some static function and it reads the value from attribute.

Comment: Yes. Use `controllerObject.GetType().GetCustomAttributes`.

Answer (score 0):

No differently that reading any other attribute.

```
        Type myType = typeof(MyClass1);
        // Get the members associated with MyClass1.
        MemberInfo[] myMembers = myType.GetMembers();

        // Display the attributes for each of the members of MyClass1. 
        for(int i = 0; i < myMembers.Length; i++)
        {
            Object[] myAttributes = myMembers[i].GetCustomAttributes(true);
            if(myAttributes.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nThe attributes for the member {0} are: \n", myMembers[i]);
                for(int j = 0; j < myAttributes.Length; j++)
                    Console.WriteLine("The type of the attribute is {0}.", myAttributes[j]);
            }
        }
```

If you are looking for a specific attribute:

```
myMembers[i].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AttributeClassName),true);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am sure these are like preprocessor directives and can't be obtained at runtime. You can do something similar to:

```
[OutputCache(
    NoStore = HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled, 
    Duration=(HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)?0:15
)]
public ActionResult RenderSomething(int somethingID)
{
...
}
```

OR:

```
if DEBUG
    [OutputCache(
        NoStore = HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled, 
        Duration = 0)]
#else
    [OutputCache(
        NoStore = HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled, 
        Duration = 15)]    
#endif
```

I don't think you can get the value of the attribute in your class function implementation.

Comment: After reading T McKeown's answer below. I was proven wrong. You can obtain the values at run-time. Don't think you can change the values though.

Comment: I had a similar issue and I thought we had the same issue. It turned out mine issue was with the ability to overwrite the directives. You are asking if they are readable in a function they decorate and T McKeown showed a way this can be done.